# Android Widget Works in Lollipop, but NOT in KitKat

Tags: android, android-widget, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a clock widget that updates every minute. It renders a bitmap and replaces an imageview. This is to use a custom font in a widget. Below I showed the important pieces of my code. My problem is that the widget is there, but nothing shows up. I can still tap the widget to bring up the settings, so I know it's there. It's like the service update isn't working correctly in Kitkat but it does in Lollipop. Any suggestions?

```
public class DigitalClockWidget_2x1 extends AppWidgetProvider {   
public RemoteViews mRemoteViews;
static String APP_SETTINGS = "8BitSettings";

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(UpdateTimeService.UPDATE_TIME));
}



@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);       
    mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);        
    Intent LaunchIntent = getLaunchIntent(context);
    PendingIntent clickPendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, LaunchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, clickPendIntent);
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),DigitalClockWidget_2x1.class.getName());
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(componentName, mRemoteViews);
    context.startService(new Intent(UpdateTimeService.UPDATE_TIME));



}

public static Intent getLaunchIntent(Context context){
    SharedPreferences clockSettings = context.getSharedPreferences("ClockSettings", 0);
    String launchString = clockSettings.getString("tappedAction", APP_SETTINGS);
    if(launchString.compareTo(APP_SETTINGS) == 0){
        return new Intent(context, SettingsPage.class);
    }
    return context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(launchString);

}

public static final class UpdateTimeService extends Service {
    static final String UPDATE_TIME = "org.penguinproductions.eight_bit_clock.action.UPDATE_TIME_2x1";
    RemoteViews mRemoteViews;
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private final static IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    int textColor = 0;
    boolean tweentyfourHour = false;
    SharedPreferences clockSettings;
    String APP_SETTINGS = "8BitSettings";

    static {
        mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();           
        mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        registerReceiver(mTimeChangedReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mTimeChangedReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (intent != null) {
            if (UPDATE_TIME.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                updateTime();
            }
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mTimeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                
            updateTime();
        }
    };

    private void updateTime() {

        mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        mRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        String date = DateFormat.format(getString(R.string.date_format), mCalendar).toString();

        mRemoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView_txt, buildUpdate(getTodaysTime(), mCalendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM), date));

        ComponentName mComponentName = new ComponentName(this, DigitalClockWidget_2x1.class);
        AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
        mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mComponentName, mRemoteViews);



        Intent LaunchIntent = getLaunchIntent(getBaseContext());
        PendingIntent clickPendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 0, LaunchIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mRemoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root, clickPendIntent);
       mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getBaseContext());
        mAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mComponentName, mRemoteViews);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

The issue seems to have to do with the Bitmap rendering. I replaced the imageview with a textview and it worked. So the Bitmap isn't displaying in KitKat, but it does in Lollipop

```
public Bitmap buildUpdate(String time, int AMPM, String date) {
         Log.v("Penguin", "Building time string:" + time);

        clockSettings = this.getSharedPreferences("ClockSettings", 0);
        boolean showDate = clockSettings.getBoolean("showDate", true);
        boolean showampm = clockSettings.getBoolean("ampm", true);
        boolean leading0 = clockSettings.getBoolean("leading0", true);
        textColor = clockSettings.getInt("clockColor", Color.WHITE);
        int dateColor = clockSettings.getInt("dateColor", Color.WHITE);



        Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(2500, 1100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        int fontSize = 425;
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Typeface clock = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/PressStart2P.ttf");
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setSubpixelText(true);
        paint.setTypeface(clock);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(textColor);

        paint.setTextSize(fontSize);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

        myCanvas.drawText(time, myBitmap.getWidth() / 2, fontSize+200, paint);

        paint.setTextSize(100);
        if(showampm) {
            // alert("AMPM");
            String ampm = "AM";
            if (AMPM == 1) ampm = "PM";
            myCanvas.drawText(ampm, (myBitmap.getWidth() / 2) + ((time.length() * fontSize) / 2) + 100, 300, paint);
        }

        paint.setTextSize(125);

        if(showDate) {
            paint.setColor(dateColor);
            myCanvas.drawText(date, myBitmap.getWidth() / 2, (myBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 400), paint);
        }
        return myBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the size limit for my older phone running KitKat only allows for texture sizes no bigger than 2048x2048 pixels. My bitmap was 2500x1100, so scaling it down has fixed the issue